# Why am I seeing a "Reseller channel 2c95500b-ea86-4b13-8bb5-b2f0c2fa8200 is invalid" error when attempting to create storage

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-studio

I am attempting to create Cloud Object Storage to work in conjunction with a Watson Studio service instance. However, when I attempt to create it, the following error message is displayed:
“Reseller channel 2c95500b-ea86-4b13-8bb5-b2f0c2fa8200 is invalid.”

How can I create the storage that I need?

Answer (score 1):

When you attempt to create the cloud object storage instance through the Watson Studio service, a link sends you to a storage provisioning page. However, you are unable to provision the storage instance. As a workaround, you can create the Cloud Object Storage service manually through the IBM Cloud Catalog at the following URL: https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/cloud-object-storage

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. Turns out when you create the new account it will ask you for a location for services and by default it's set to "Dallas". However changing that to London/Tokyo fixed this issue for me. I needed it for IBM Course on Coursera. I would recommend making a new account with services location set to London / Tokyo. It'll instantly fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by first creating the object storage before creating the Watson Studio service.

Answer (score 0):

After you have created a cloud object storage service with the [direct link to the service](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/cloud-object-storage)

While creating a new project On Watson Studio, you will see an option to Add a cloud Object Storage service under **Define storage**  to your project in the project creation page. Once you click Add, you can either use an existing Service as you have now or create a new COS service.

[image]

For more details instructions check [this section](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-create-deploy-retrain-machine-learning-model#import_data_project) of the solution tutorial